# Idris REPL can't find import while the program compiles

Tags: haskell-stack, idris

I cloned [this Idris library](https://github.com/eckart/glfw-idris) and it compiles fine with the necessary dependencies. There is an `example/` directory, which utilizes the library (imports some of its modules), and it compiles and runs fine as well. However, when I attempt to run the REPL in Atom, a familiar error message is displayed:

```
Can't find import Graphics/Util/GlfwConfig
```

Which is interesting because when `make` is executed, the following is one of the output lines:

```
Installing Graphics/Util/Glfw.ibc to /home/jan/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/lts-11.17/8.2.2/share/x86_64-linux-ghc-8.2.2/idris-1.3.0/libs/glfw/Graphics/Util
```

Which seems to suggest that this module has been installed.

I'm probably misinterpreting some part of the process of Haskell/Idris/Stack installs here and Idris modules, so what am I supposed to do/understand here?

Comment: I should have asked before answering: but what happens if you launch the REPL outside of Atom, i.e. does `stack ghci` work correctly?

Comment: hey @dave I'm not following what role would that have here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is quite simply that the project contains two `ipkg` files. One for the library and one for the test/example.
The one in `example/hello`:

```
package test

opts = "-p effects -p glfw " 

executable = hello
main = Main
```

includes the dependency to the idris package glfw but is not seen by Atom if you invoke Atom in the toplevel directory. To verify, please switch to the directory `example/hello` and invoke `atom .` and try from there. Now the ipkg file is in the toplevel directoy and will be picked up by Atom.

Answer (score 0):

When using `stack` the REPL has to be launched via stack: `stack ghci` rather than just `ghci`.  This will compile and load the modules in the library.

I'm not familiar with Atom, but according to [this](https://atom-haskell.github.io/extra-packages/ide-haskell-repl/), the REPL will attempt to guess the correct `ghci` command to run.  It is getting the wrong command and not running `stack ghci`.